# $P[(A' | B') or (B' | A')]?$

Tags: probability

Known:
Assume $A$ and $B$ are dependent (that is they are not independent).

- $P(A | B') = 0.96 \implies P(A' | B') = 0.04$
- $P(B | A') = 0.73 \implies P(B' | A') = 0.27$
- $P(B') = 0.3 \implies P(B) = 0.7$
- $P(A') = 0.7 \implies P(A) = 0.3$

Questions:

**1)** Does the following make sense mathematically: $P[(A' | B') ~\mbox{or}~ (B' | A')]$?  If it does not make sense, is there an explanation as to why it doesn't make sense?

**2)** If **#1** does make sense, then:

- $P[(A' | B') ]~\mbox{or}~ (B' | A')] = P(A' | B') + P(B' | A') - P[(A' | B') ~\mbox{and}~ (B' | A')] = 0.04 + 0.27 - P[(A' | B') ~\mbox{and}~ (B' | A')] $

Is it possible to find $P[(A' | B') ]~\mbox{and}~ (B' | A')]$ with the known information?

Comment: It does not make sense because $(A|B)$ does not make sense/does not exist/is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(A|B)$ is defined as the induced probability measure on $B$, i.e., it is a shortcut for "probability of $A\cap B$ as an event in $(B,P|B,\Omega|B)$".

In other words, "$A|B$" and "$B|A$" are *not* events to which we can apply the "or" operation.

Comment: Thank you for answering with a theoretical statement and a layman's terms statement.